# Post status update to Facebook from iOS application

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I am creating an iOS application and I am adding some sharing options. I already downloaded the Facebook 3.0 SDK and placed it in my project in accordance with the Facebook developer page. All I need my application to do is **post text-only status updates** to Facebook when a certain button is clicked on an UIActionSheet. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"];
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                                  // session might now be open.
                                  if (session.isOpen)
                                      //don't know what to do from here
                              }];
    }
}
```

**I don't know where to proceed from here.** The authentication takes place and then the Facebook app on my iPhone opens and that is the end of it. Also, if there is anything else I should add that I am missing PLEASE let me know. I am new to Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook's iOS documentation covers this very nicely in their [sample application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/#samples) and tutorials.

**Specifically**

> HelloFacebookSample: combines use of FBLoginView,
>   FBProfilePictureView, FBFriendsPickerViewController,
>   FBPlacePickerViewController, and FBRequest for profile access, status
>   updates and photo uploading.

- From developer.facebook.com